# Parallel processing on linq query supplying parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, parallel.foreach

```
            List<ContactGroup> contactGroups = new List<ContactGroup>();
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            contactGroups.AddRange(dbEnt.ClientContactGroups.Where(x => x.ClientID == ClientID && x.IsDeleted == false).Select(x => new ContactGroup { ClientID = x.ClientID, ClientContactGroupID = x.ClientContactGroupID, ContactGroupName = x.ContactGroupName }).ToList());
            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            {
                contactGroups.Where(x => x.ContactGroupName.Contains(SearchText)).ToList();
            }
            List<SP_GroupContacts_Result> groupContacts_Results = new List<SP_GroupContacts_Result>();
            stopwatch.Start();
            Parallel.ForEach(contactGroups, groups =>
            {
                groups.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
                groups.Contacts.AddRange((from cc in dbEnt.ClientContacts
                        join rt in dbEnt.ResponseTeamUserMappings on cc.ClientContactID equals rt.CMTMemberUserID
                        join cr in dbEnt.ClientRoles on rt.ClientRoleID equals cr.ClientRoleID
                        where cc.ClientContactGroupID == groups.ClientContactGroupID && cc.IsActive == true && cc.IsDeleted == false
                        select new Contact
                        {
                            ClientContactID= cc.ClientContactID,
                            FirstName = cc.FirstName,
                            LastName = cc.LastName,
                            ProfileImage = cc.ProfileImage,
                            RoleName = cr.ClientRoleName,
                            Email= cc.Email,
                            ContactNumber= cc.MobilePhone
                        }).ToList());
            });
            stopwatch.Stop();
```

I need to do these process in parallel but I dont have any information about paralleling processes in c#. I have tried different approaches but failing to make it work. It's failing in parallel.foreach part.

Following is the error i am getting stack trace:

> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Expression()
>      at WebAPI.BLL.Comms.CommsBusinessLayer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ContactGroup>b__3(ContactGroup groups) in D:\API-ComposeComms\WebAPI.BLL\Comms\CommsBusinessLayer.cs:line 61
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()

Message is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Why do you **need** to do it in parallel? this is likely an XY problem, and a misunderstanding what parallel DB workloads will achieve.

Comment: my api is loading slow because of the time it's taking to process. it's taking 13 seconds manager has told me to reduce it to below 3 seconds.

Comment: Parallel processing against a database is not the solution to a performance problem 98.234324% of the time. Its like saying my car is slow, i better build more roads. You need to work on the actual query, work out where the bottle neck is, you can do this by looking at the generated sql, and profiling that against your db

Comment: actually query is working normally fine but because it has to be called multiple times within the for loop api is loading slow.

Comment: So instead of using `where x == y` you should try creating `where x in y` so that you only have one query instead of multiple. In linq you can do this with `.Contains`

Comment: okay thanks chronicle i will try that.

Comment: do you still need help on this? at first glance I see two problems with the code; 
the first problem is that Lists are not thread safe you should use ConcurrentBag<T> instead of lists when dealing with multiple threads,2 unless you are using an oracle db one instance of dbcontext is only able to query 1 at a time. I mean each select statement must be executed one after another but in the parallel foreach it will try querying them at the same time and this would give you an error

Comment: the parallel foreach didn't work in this case but in one other case i tried it worked but then it increased the execution time so i removed it altogether.